# Posting large file React.js & .net 5

Tags: c#, reactjs, file-upload, .net-5

I have a .net 5 API which has an endpoint that accepts a model consisting of an IFormFile File, string Description and string Name.

When Posting a form using axios from my react client everything works just fine using a 55.500kb file however when posting a file of 250,000kb the request appears to leave the client without any issue but the entire request is null when the endpoint is hit.

My API endpoint is decorated with RequestSizeLimit of 2147483648 and is mirrored in the web.config.

I'm guessing the reason is that the file being posted is too large but not 100% sure on this. If this is the reason do I need to somehow stream or chunk the request or is something else the root cause of this issue?

React function to post form:

```
    handleSubmit = async () => {
        this.setState({ componentState: LOADING }, async () => {
            let form = new FormData();
            form.append("title", this.state.title);
            form.append("reference", this.state.reference);
            form.append("description", this.state.description);
            form.append("price", this.state.price);
            form.append("scormFile", this.state.file);

            let response = await uploadCourseAsync(form);
            
            if (response.isSuccessStatusCode) {
                this.setState({ componentState: SUCCESS });
            }
            else {
                this.setState({ errors: response.errors })
            }
        })
    }
```

.net endpoint to receive request:

```
        [RequestSizeLimit(2147483648)]
        [HttpPost("UploadCourse")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadCourse([FromForm] CreateCourseCommand command)
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            await command.ScormFile.CopyToAsync(ms);
            var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());
            var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
            {
                {byteArrayContent, command.ScormFile.Name, command.ScormFile.FileName},
                {new StringContent(command.Description), "Description"},
                {new StringContent(command.Reference), "Reference"},
                {new StringContent(command.Price), "Price"},
                {new StringContent(command.Title), "Title"},
                {new StringContent(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Id")?.Value ?? string.Empty), "UploadedById"},
                {byteArrayContent, command.ScormFile.Name, command.ScormFile.FileName}
            };

            var url = _serviceUrlConfig.CourseService + "/course/uploadcourse";
            var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(url, multipartContent);
            return Ok(response);
        }
```

Any advice would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

POST message max. size is usually limited by http servers to 2 GB. This code allows you to download files of any size.

**React component:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

export default function LargeFileUploader(props) {
    const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 10485760; // 10MB chunk sizes.
    var start;
    var part;
    var SIZE = 0;
    var xhr;
    var fileGuid = '';
    const [file, setFile] = useState('');

    function sendRequest() {
        SIZE = file.size;
        start = 0;
        part = 0;
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        uploadFile(part);
    }
    function uploadFile() {
        var blobFile = file.slice(start, BYTES_PER_CHUNK + start);
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("file", blobFile);
        fd.append("fileguid", fileGuid);
        fd.append('part', part);
        fd.append('rawFileName', file.name);
        fd.append('partsTotal', Math.ceil(SIZE / BYTES_PER_CHUNK));

        var url = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/" + 'Files' + "/" + 'Upload';
        xhr.open("POST", url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        xhr.send(fd);
    }

    function uploadComplete(event) {
        if (event.currentTarget.status === 200) {
            if (start < SIZE) {
                start = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
                part++;
                uploadFile();
            }
        } else {
            alert('error');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="largeFileUploader">
            <form onSubmit={(event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                fileGuid = uuid();
                sendRequest();
            }}>                
                <div>
                    <input type="file" multiple={false}
                        onChange={(event) => {
                            setFile(event.target.files[0]);
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                        <button type="submit" disabled={!file}>Upload</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**.NET 5 Controller method:**

```
    [HttpPost]        
    [Route("Upload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormCollection formData)
    {
        try
        {
            var part = int.Parse(formData["part"].ToString());
            var fileGuid = Guid.Parse(formData["fileGuid"].ToString());
            var rawFileName = formData["rawFileName"].ToString();
            string filePath = Path.Combine(_appConfig.DocumentFilesPath, fileGuid.ToString() + "." + rawFileName.Split(".").Last());

            using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, part == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
            {
                await formData.Files.First().CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                fileStream.Close();
            }

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
        }

        return StatusCode(500);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue without any client said changes. When posting a form the limits set using the web.config and in the attribute decorating the controller are seemingly ignored. The solution was to add the following code to the ConfigureServices method in the Startup.cs

```
         services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>  
            {
                o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
                o.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                o.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
                o.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            });
```