# Upload large file with axios react and .net core

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core, file-upload, axios

I need to upload a large file(100MB) on the iis server.
Why the following code it's works with smaller files(13MB).
The error I got on uploading large files is :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://localhost:44331/api/Files/uploadFile?hidden=false' from
> origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Thanks for your help.

This is frontend snippet with axios and react:

```
public upload = async (filesForUploading: File[], progressLogger: (progress: IProgress) => void, 
hidden?: boolean) => {
    const createPostRequest = (item: File) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", item, item.name);
        const request = this.agent.post<IFile>(`${this.url}/uploadFile?hidden=${hidden || false}`, 
       formData, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            },
            onUploadProgress: (progressEvent: ProgressEvent) => {
                
                progressLogger({ file: item, uploaded: progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total, 
 id: URL.createObjectURL(item) });
                
                
            },
        });
        return request;
    };
    const requests = filesForUploading.map(createPostRequest);

    const getData = (all: Array<AxiosResponse<IFile>>) => all.map(res => res.data);
    const response = await Promise.all(requests);
    return getData(response);
};
```

This is the backend method .net core:

```
       [HttpPost("uploadFile", Name = nameof(UploadFile))]
       [ProducesResponseType(200)]
       [ProducesResponseType(400)]
       [ProducesResponseType(404)]
       [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
       public async Task<ActionResult<FileViewModel>> UploadFile(IFormFile file, bool hidden = false)
       {
        FileViewModel uploadedFile = null;
        User loggedUser = await _userService.GetLoggedUser(User);
        try
        {
            uploadedFile = await _fileService.UploadFile(file, loggedUser, hidden);

        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            return NotFound(error);
        }

        return Ok(uploadedFile);
    }
```

Comment: The error message your getting coupled with the reason for it your giving doesn't make sense. Are you sure that the error stems from a large file being uploaded? So, does the exact same code succeed when uploading a small file?

Comment: yes it is. is the same code.

Comment: If you need to uplod files of any size, you could use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69990677/10203847

Answer (score 0):

The default file size limit in IIS is 30 MB as far as I know.
In order to increase it, you should specify the limit in the *requestLimits* section of your web.config file. You can find the description and example in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/):
Also, you may need to configure *IISServerOptions* and *KestrelServerOptions* in your Startup.cs. The example you may find in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987343/request-body-too-large).

Anyway, the error message says that there is a problem with CORS policies, not with file size. I may assume that the problem is caused not only by the file size limit, but by other configuration mistakes as well.